# Logging to Seq works fine in IIS Express but not in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, serilog, seq

I have an ASP.Net Core app where I have configured Seq and Serilog. When I run the app in Kestrel or in IIS Express, the logs appear in the Seq server (running in Docker at http://localhost:5341/)

When I run the same app in IIS on Windows 10, no logs appear in Seq.

Here are the settings for the application pool:

[image]

Here is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyApp": "Server=.;Database=MyApp;User ID=sa;Password=letmein123456;"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId", "WithAssemblyName", "WithAssemblyVersion" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      { "Name": "Debug" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "shared": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341"
        }
      }
    ],
    "preserveStaticLogger": false,
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "My.Test.App"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I setup Serilog/Seq:

```
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
```

Any clue to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you have an ASP.NET Core app, why is your app pool configured to use a .NET CLR version? You should use "no managed code".

Comment: Are the File sink logs showing up? Did you try enabling the [self log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) as described in the documentation?

Comment: Changing .NET CLR to no managed code did the trick! Thank you!